# Swift downcasting fails

Tags: swift, casting

I have encountered very weird behavior and I really can't make heads or tails of it. I am trying to store class types in the array and want to call later on but it doesn't work. Here is my code

```
class BaseClass {

    class func getDetails() -> String {
        return "aaaaaa"
    }
}

class Foo: BaseClass {

    override class func getDetails() ->String {
        return "foo"
    }
}


class Bar: BaseClass {
    override class func getDetails() ->String {
        return "bar"
    }
}

var arr = [Foo.self, Bar.self]
func test1 () {

    var x = Foo.self
    println(x.getDetails()) //prints foo
    if let y = arr[0] as? Foo.Type {
        println(y.getDetails()) //doesn't execute

    }
    if let z = arr[0] as? BaseClass.Type {
        println(z.getDetails()) //doesn't execute
    }
    if let t = arr[0] as? BaseClass {
        println(t.dynamicType.getDetails()) //doesn't execute
    }
    // lets crash
    var w = arr[0] as! Foo
    //Could not cast value of type 'Test.Foo' (0x1085f17f0) to 'Test.Foo' (0x1085f1830).

}
```

I am especially puzzled by

> Could not cast value of type 'Test.Foo' (0x1085f17f0) to 'Test.Foo'
>   (0x1085f1830)

error. How can I refer to classes in the array by downcasting to `BaseClass` to that I can use its `getDetails` function

Comment: It's strange your implementation, I don"t know how to explain.  There are many problems, for example : you declare getDetails as class function but it seems that you want to call as instance function. Your cast is illegal also. It should be var `w = arr[0] as! Foo.Type` to be legal

Comment: @HoaParis There is nothing illegal there, read it again.

Comment: @Sulthan : alinoz just gave an answer that is what I want to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... peculiar. This

```
var arr = [Foo.self, Bar.self]
println(arr.count)
println(arr)
```

will print 2 then crash, but this works fine:

```
var arr: [BaseClass.Type] = [Foo.self, Bar.self]
println(arr.count)
println(arr)
```

except that you get warnings later in your code about the `as? BaseClass.Type` test always succeeding (and, thus, not being needed) and the `as? BaseClass` test always failing (expected, since the contents of the array are not *instances* of the classes but their *types*).

In the section *Defining a Class Hierarchy for Type Casting* of [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338) guide, we find

> Swift’s type checker is able to deduce that Movie and Song have a
>   common superclass of MediaItem, and so it infers a type of [MediaItem]
>   for the library array:

```
let library = [
    Movie(name: "Casablanca", director: "Michael Curtiz"),
    Song(name: "Blue Suede Shoes", artist: "Elvis Presley"),
    Movie(name: "Citizen Kane", director: "Orson Welles"),
    Song(name: "The One And Only", artist: "Chesney Hawkes"),
    Song(name: "Never Gonna Give You Up", artist: "Rick Astley")
]
// the type of "library" is inferred to be [MediaItem]
```

It looks like you're doing something similar, and so one would expect it to work, but you're not - you're storing the types of the classes, not instances of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was very interesting error indeed. As a side note it was also crashing playground. Adding ```:[BaseClass.Type]``` solved all my problems. It really bothered me that why it couldn't cast BaseClass.Type. Anyway, the reason I was using class function is because I want to get static variable of class but getting variables of protocols are not implemented that is why I turned to sub classing. PS: I think ```:``` on first line you posted is small typo.

Comment: Ah, yes, it was a typo. Thanks. It's been corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

So Foo.self is equivalent of the [Object class] from objective c.
So in

```
var arr = [Foo.self, Bar.self]
```

you are basically creating an array of class types (not objects of base class BaseClass - Foo, Bar)

On

```
var w = arr[0] as! Foo
```

you are trying to cast the Class type to an object of that class type. This operation is not possible but you try to enforce it by using ! and this will generate your crash.

To get the reason why the other downcasting are not working try this in your playgroung:

```
println("\(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(Foo.self))")
println("\(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(Foo.Type))")
```

Comment: we know that, the question is more about the cases before.

Comment: as @Sulthan mentions, my problem was downcasting Foo to BaseClass. Last line was there because I was trying every possible combination. Sorry if it miss-leaded you.

Comment: @Meanteacher have you try the last 2 lines in your playground? What are the types of Foo.self? And what is the type of Foo.Type? You can not downcast arr[0] to BaseClass because arr[0] is not an object of type Foo but is an object of class type.

Comment: I get ```Test.Foo.Type``` and ```Test.Type.Type``` As I mentioned before, my problem was down casting Foo to BaseClass so that I can use their class function. I don't want to store it as object then I had to initialize and  use its methods. It all happened because Swift couldn't down cast if we don't specify the type of items as [BaseClass] I think it should have warned when I was creating the array because if [BaseClass] isn't there, it can't downcast. Thanks again for your explanations. I appreciate as a new programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're using an older version of Swift. I find that in 6.3, you need to provide a type for `arr` (I suspect that 6.2 is resolving this to something not useful, which is probably the source of your problems):

```
let arr: [BaseClass.Type] = [Foo.self, Bar.self]
```

Let's walk through the rest:

```
let x = Foo.self
println("x:" + x.getDetails()) //prints foo
```

Yep; that should be expected.

```
if let y = arr[0] as? Foo.Type {
    println("y" + y.getDetails()) //doesn't execute
}
```

I find that it does execute in 6.3. That said, it is unnecessary, since `BaseClass` includes a `getDetails` method. The following works just as well:

```
let y2 = arr[0]
println("y2:" + y2.getDetails())
```

Next:

```
if let z = arr[0] as? BaseClass.Type {
    println("z:" + z.getDetails()) //doesn't execute
}
```

I find that it does execute, as you'd expect, though it's unnecessary.

```
if let t = arr[0] as? BaseClass {
    println(t.dynamicType.getDetails()) //doesn't execute
}
```

That can't work (and you get a warning). A class is not an instance.

```
let w = arr[0] as! Foo
```

And that will crash as expected, since a class is not an instance.

So if you do this correctly, no type casting is needed. You can just have an array of classes, and call them. That said, you should always think hard in Swift about whether you really need a class here. Often the better solution is a struct and a protocol.

Comment: `[AnyObject.Type]` would work too. I think that Swift was inferring the type to `[AnyObject]` and then the casts have to fail because it thinks the array actually contains instances and not classes.

Comment: I am using Version 6.3 (6D570) with Swift 1.2. It didn't required me to supply type of array. It is interesting if it is different on your side. @wltrup has provided correct answer which worked for me. I was using protocol, but accessing members of protocol type is unimplemented.